# Manage namespaced development libraries in Google App Engine (PyDev)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, pydev, libraries, symlink

While developing GAE applications, in-house libraries are developed as well. These libraries use namespace packages.

To demonstrate, I have two libraries with the following file structure.

**First-lib:**

```
first
  |--src  # Sources of first
  |  `--spam  # Namespace 'spam'
  |     |--eggs  # Namespace 'spam.eggs'
  |     |  `--*
  |     `--sausage  # Namespace 'spam.sausage'
  |        `--*
  `--test  # Unit tests of first
     `--*
```

**Second-lib:**

```
second
  |--src  # Sources of second
  |  `--spam  # Namespace 'spam'
  |     |--bacon  # Namespace 'spam.bacon'
  |     |  `--*
  |     `--tomatoes  # Namespace 'spam.tomatoes'
  |        `--*
  `--test  # Unit tests of second
     `--*
```

Currently we symlink both libraries in a directory in the application root creating the following file structure.

**App:**

```
app
  |--src  # Sources of app
  |  |--lib  # Plain directory
  |  |  |--first  # Symlink to first/src
  |  |  `--second  # Symlink to second/src
  |  |--fries  # App specific package
  |  |  `--*
  |  |--app.yaml
  |  `--appengine_config.py
  `--test  # Unit tests of app
     `--*
```

In the `appengine_config` module the `sys.path` is modified so it contains the symlinks. Everything can be imported as expected.

The problem with this is that the symlinks are not resolved by the GAE dev_appserver. When a breakpoint is set in the real path (not the symlinked path) PyDev issues a warning:

> pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: <real-path> (will have no effect)

The trick is to add a breakpoint in the symlinked file. This is very annoying.

Is there a way to disable the GAE sandbox so modules can be imported without symlinking or to work around it? The goal is to make breakpoints work when the libraries are in the workspace.